# analysis of higher orden function in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I found the following code about Higher Order Functions in Scheme:

```
(define make-double (lambda (f)
                      (lambda (x)
                        (f x x))))
(define square (make-double *))
```

For what I see make-double receives as an argument a function:f, and this function receives and x as argument. This argument x is doubled and  make-double return the function f with this x value doubled. Is it like that?

The call to the function square is straightforward, just call the function make-double and the function *, but how can I run this program? When I execute it with:

```
square
```

It returns to me:

```
(lambda (x) (f x x))
```

How to interpret that? I suppose this function allowed to print an element twice, but maybe I am mistaken? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try evaluating `(square 42)`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Typing `square` just prints the value of `square`, which is a function.

```
(lambda (x) (f x x))
```

Tells you that `square` is a function accepting one argument, whose value will be used as both arguments of the function bound by `f`, which is in this case is `*`.